# How to write pulse width systemverilog assertion when width is configurable

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

The scenario is:
  Signal `active` can be either 1 cycle, 2 cycle, 3 cycle or 4 cycle wide depending on `config[1:0]` input to the module

Easiest way to write property for this is:

```
property p_PropA;
    @(posedge clk) $rose active ##config ~active;
endproperty
```

But it is syntactically wrong.
What is correct way of writing this assertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a local variable, see [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 16.10 *Local variables*

Here is a simple example:

```
property p_PropA;
  int count;
  @(posedge clk)
  ($rose(active),count=config) |->
    (active,count--)[*] ##1 (~active && count==0);
endproperty
```

Comment: Thanks, How is [\*] used? As I understand it [\*] stands for seq [*0] or seq [*1:$]. This will decrement count every cycle until active is not true. But then active can deassert 6 clocks later and count will be negative which fails on count == 0 check. Is that correct? And I'll need to make sure my simulation doesn't end until last active is deasserted.

Comment: `seq[*]` is equivelent to `seq[*0:$]` (see 16.9.2 in the [lrm](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)). Yes, the counter could go negative. To may long pulse give fail messages sooner, you can use: `(active && count>0,count--)[*] ##1 (~active && count==0)`. You can code it other ways too (my is an example), but they will all require local variables.